# Set de GAP tolerance for Cplex in java

Tags: java, cplex

i'm working in Cplex with Java  to solve a MIP an trying  to set a parameter with

```
cplex_model.setParam(IloCplex::EpGap, 0.01);
```

But it always appear the red line of error and i had seen many examples and they all use it like that....why is not working?

Comment: What version of CPLEX are you using? I think that this parameter name was changed in 12.6.

Comment: Yes, i'm using 12.6.   i found this site http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/05/11/setting-cplex-parameters-in-java-revisited/ something ( i don't quite undertand very well the idea ) ...but is there anything simpler to use?

Answer (score 2):

Paul Rubin is really *very* good on many aspects of CPLEX. I really recommend that you come back and read his stuff again and again as you will learn a lot from doing so. But what he presents on that page is probably more complex than you need when you are just starting out.

Also the syntax IloCplex::EpGap looks to me like C++ rather than Java, and is the old (pre 12.6) name of that parameter.

Try looking in the CPLEX Java examples for uses of cplex.setParam(...). I found plenty of examples there, such as setting the search strategy. The name of the relative MIPGAP tolerance (from the 12.6 manual) should be IloCplex.Param.MIP.Tolerances.MIPGap. So try something like:

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex.Param.MIP.Tolerances.MIPGap, 1.0e-5);
```

Hope that this helps you...
Tim

Comment: Yes!! that worked...thanks a lot! i google that a lot but it didn't appear :P